# Is it Possible to terminate the std::async thread?

Tags: c++, c++17, c++20

I have the code below which I am calling it asynchronously for downloading a file, I want to terminate the thread ? How to achieive this ?

```
std::future<BOOL> fut = std::async(std::launch::async,&download::downloadBlob2File,&t_oftcdownload,stol(blocksize), downldUrl, token,name, path, ID);
 std::chrono::hours span (2);
 int t_iResult = -1;

 if (fut.wait_for(span)==std::future_status::timeout)
 {
  t_iResult=0;
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it, but only in the sense that you can write the code yourself. You can build a mechanism to communicate to the other thread that you want it to halt, and that thread can frequently check this mechanism to see if it is being told to abort.

There is no mechanism built into `async` to help you do this. C++20 has [the `std::stop_source`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/stop_source) and [`std::stop_token`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/stop_token) types, which are such a communication mechanism. But you have to pass a `stop_token` to the asynchronous function, and it must be written to manually check this mechanism periodically to see if it should stop.

C++ has no mechanism to *force* a thread to stop; stopping a thread is something the target thread has to *agree* to do, and thus it has to be designed to do it.